# Split GeoJson Polygon into multiple polygons in Openlayers 4

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers, geojson

Is it possible to split geojson polygon or multipolygon feature loaded into a `ol.layer.Vector` into multiple geojson features using any of `openlayers`'s `ol.interaction.Interaction`. I know that you can draw using `ol.interaction.Draw` and reshape an exising polygon using `ol.interaction.Modify` but I need to split a polygon into muliple polygons.

Comment: That would be difficult, 'coz basically polygons are just "points"..it is hard to determine if it splitting it will form polygon.

Comment: Is this possible in any other libraraies, say google map or leaflet.?? @SachiTekina

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: any update on this question

Comment: @Johnson I'm able to achieve it using this link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216977/how-to-split-the-polygon-operation-using-of-jsts